# How can I map an IP Address to an eight character long string?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, hash, hashtable

I've a list of server ip addresses that my application interacts to in order to collect live data. And the collected data is sent to slots in another system. These slots are identified by eight character length strings. And I would like to create this slots programmatically. I would like to create a method that will map an ip address of a server to an eight character string. eg. given 192.80.24.200 it will return SLOT0001 I assume a hash function will be a good solution but I'm not sure how it's implemented.

The application is a C# Winforms .Net Framework 4.0. And the servers are windows based servers.

Comment: do you want to obfuscate the IP or would reversing the string to the original IP be acceptable ?

Comment: I prefer a solution that will obfuscate but one that will allow figuring out the IP from the string will be acceptable.

Comment: Does your solution need to support IPv6 addresses?

Comment: @ScottSmith Good question. At the moment we are only concerned about targeting IPv4 addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IP address is 4 bytes long, which can be directly written as eight hexadecimal characters:

```
void Main()
{
    var addr = IPAddress.Parse("192.80.24.200");
    var str = IPAddressToString(addr);
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}

public string IPAddressToString(IPAddress address)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder(8);
    foreach(var b in address.GetAddressBytes())
    {
        result.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, convert the IP address into a 32-bit number, and convert that to 8 hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 1):

Eight characters is a HEX representation.

- Decimal: 192.80.24.200
- HEX: C0.50.18.C8
- dotless HEX string: C05018C8

this is faster and simple way to pack IP into eight bytes